# Where in asp.net-mvc do I put code for user authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, authentication

I'm developîng a MVC intranet with windows authentication.

I have a folder with views that only certain roles can see.

I have a web.config file in that folder

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrator, ICCManager"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I want to write code to see if the user is in one of these roles, if not redirect him to a info page.

This is my first MVC project and I still don't totally know my way around. So I have no idea where to actually write this code. A bit stupid, I know, but I just don't get it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a good place to start:

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/11/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-1/

You will want to implement a membership provider which can figure out what roles the user has, etc. Very customizable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to configure the access to the views directly, you configure the access to the action methods which will in turn return views.

You do this by decoration single action methods or whole controllers with the [Authorize] attribute:

```
// All actions in this class cannot be called by anonymous users
[Authorize]
public class MyController {

    // This action is just callable by users in role Admin
    [Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        return View();
    }

    // This action is callable by any authorized user (inherited from class)
    public ActionResult MyAction() {
        return View();
    }
}

// Actions from this controller can be called by any user (even unauthorized)
public calls AnotherController {
}
```

When a non allowed user tries to access a page, the user is redirected to the action you configure in the `loginUrl` attribute of the `authentication` element in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Membership/Login" ... />
</authentication>
```

Comment: With that, the user does not see the page, which is nice, but I would like to redirect him to a certain page.

Answer (score 0):

The code in which you would check the record in the database of a particular user would be in the `model` class and you can return the results from there to controller.

In `controller` you can handle the logic, like if user is not authorized than redirect him to info page else to profile page etc.

For more info go through this once it will help clearing a lot of other concepts regarding ASP MVC.

[ASP.NET MVC Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/mvc_intro.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [AuhtorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx#using_authorizeattribute) on controller method to set restriction to action and in web.config set forms authentication in authentication tag and set logon page to page you need. If it's not logon page but just info, open global.asax and override Application_AuthenticateRequest method.

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //redirect
        }       
}
```